# Retornar array ASP 3 e popular select com each JQUERY

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp

Preciso popular um select (Html). Acredito que o passo seria esse, mas como fazer? Alguém tem um link que possa me direcionar?

1. Clicar no select (OnChange talvez)
2. Colocar os dados da Query (Consulta) em ASP nesse Array
3. Retornar esse Array para JQUERY e popular através do Each.

O foda é, como criar esse array em ASP 3, e como passar para o JQUERY e ler através do Each.

Alguém me dá uma luz de como fazer?

Comment: O que seria enviado pelo Ajax?

Comment: @sam enviado ou trazido pelo ajax? Enviado uma página asp, trazido dois campos dentro de um array para eu dar o loop com each no Jquery. Seria para popular um select.

Comment: Me parece que seu problema é mais na criação do array em ASP, porque o resto é bem simples.

Comment: @sam os dois. Tô pesquisando aqui como colocar os dados de uma query no array (ASP), tá difícil de achar algo. Primeiro tenho que resolver isso, depois penso na parte do JQUERY.

Comment: Esse array que espera seria um array simples, tipo: `array("item 1","item 2",...)`?

Comment: @sam então, não sei como tem que ficar, para dar certo lá no Jquery.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/80454/discussion-between-sam-and-rod).

Comment: @sam de eu achasse algo parecido em php, talvez me desse uma luz.

Comment: @sam dá uma olhada no chat

Comment: @sam falei com vc no chat. rs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode chamar o Ajax clicando no `select` e passar o `id` do `select` clicado como parâmetro na URL a ser requisitada. Desta forma você pode controlar quais informações serão enviadas pelo ASP com `request("id")`.

Crie um evento `click` que irá detectar o clique no `select` e enviar via `$.get` o `id` do respectivo elemento. O retorno do ASP (veremos mais a frente) irá retornar objetos com dois valores cada, separados por vírgula, onde um valor será o `value` e o outro o texto das `option` a popularem o `select` clicado.

No retorno do Ajax você converte esses objetos em array JSON com o método `JSON.parse()`, e usando `$.each` você monta o HTML das `option`. Após o `$.each` basta você jogar o HTML montado para dentro do `select` com `.html()`.

Demais explicações nos códigos.

**Exemplo do `select` com uma `id`:**

```
<select id="cursos"></select>
```

**Código do evento e do Ajax:**

```
$('select').click(function(){ // evento click
   // este if verifica se o select já foi populado
   // evitando que ele seja populado mais de uma vez
   // ao ser clicado
   if(!$('option', this).length){
      $(this).prop("disabled", true); // desabilita o select
      var id = this.id; // pega o id do select
      var url_ = 'pagina.asp?id='+id; // monto a URL do Ajax passando o id como parâmetro para o ASP

      $.get(url_, function(data){
         // aqui é o retorno do Ajax
         data = data.replace(/,$/, ''); // removo a última vírgula que virá
         data = JSON.parse('[' + data + ']'); // converto os objetos em array JSON
         var opts = ''; // declaro a variável que irá montar o HTML das options
         $.each(data, function(index, item) {
            // monto as options concatenando os valores de cada objeto
            opts += '<option value="'+item.id+'">'+item.campo+'</option>';
         });

         $('#'+id).html(opts) // envio o HTML montado para o devido select
         .prop("disabled", false); // habilita o select novamente
      });
   }
});
```

> Troque `pagina.asp` pela sua página ASP.

**Montando os objetos no ASP e retornando para o Ajax:**

No ASP você recebe o `id` enviado pelo Ajax com `request("id")`, e de acordo com o valor recebido, você monta a query ao banco de dados.

Faça o loop normal da consulta ao banco e coloque o `response.write` dentro desse loop montando os objetos que serão enviados para o Ajax. Exemplo:

```
<%
conn = conexão com o banco
set rs = conn.execute(aqui a sua query)
if not rs.eof then
   while not rs.eof
      response.write("{""id"":"""& rs("coluna_id") &""",""campo"":"""& rs("coluna_campo") &"""},")
   rs.movenext
   wend
end if
rs.close
set rs = nothing
%>
```

> A página ASP deverá ter apenas o código acima. Não é uma página normal
>   com tags.

Comment: Funcionou não. Coloquei um link no chat pra vc ver.

Comment: nada ainda, dando um alert antes dessa linha os dados estão vindo.

Comment: vou atualizar o jquery pra ver.

Comment: localhost funcionou uhuuuu. Agora quero ver porque não no server

Comment: precisaria que iniciasse um com valeu=" " (vazio) deixando a opção do usuario de não selecionar nada. Colocando <option value="">Disciplina (todas)</option> no proprio select não vai, então terei qie fazer isso antes do each no Jquery. É isso?

Comment: não dá, tem que já vir ao carregar a página e não quando clicar no select. tentei colocar no proprio select, mas ai para de trazer.

Comment: porque que ao colocar assim: <select id="disciplina" >
   <option value="">Disciplina (todas)</option>
  </select>

Comment: ele para de trazer, não entendi.

Comment: é por causa do if que eu coloquei rs.... altere para `if($('option', this).length == 1)`... mas tb tem que trocar o `$('#'+id).html(opts);` para `$('#'+id).append(opts);`

Comment: cara, valeu. Vou estudar mais aqui e tentar fazer alguns ajustes. Fazendo essa modificação do if, as vezes ele dá um bug, não carrega, tem que dar dois cliques.

Comment: só uma ultima coisa, qual a função do index na função: function(index, item)?

Comment: Blz... qualquer coisa chama aí. Isso aí que vc está querendo fazer é mamão com açúcar. Não tem que ter bug não. É muito simples: clicou no select, chama o Ajax. Agora o ideal era desabilitar o select até a resposta do Ajax.

Comment: O index é o índice da array, começando do 0

Comment: entendi. valeuuu